# Hard disk errors as when operating in battery mode (no power cable connected)

Tags: laptop, ssd, battery, sata

So i recently bought a second hand notebook because i could not resist the offer. ASUS 15.6" Notebook, Motherboard K53SK, Intel i7-2670qm, 6gb ddr3 (can upgrade to 16gb), sata-3, dvd drive, usb3.0 for € 150. The device is in very good (visual) condition.

I exchanged the 500GByte hdd with a 256GByte SATA-3 SSD, that i did not need in any other system, made a fresh ubuntu 16.04 installation and everything worked perfectly...

Until i unplugged the notebook.

I got hundereds of error messages like:

```
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector XXXX
Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 1, lost async page write
ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page: rc = [-30]
```

(i had to take a picture with my smartphone because the notebook did not respond anymore, logs could not be written to the hard drive, they were just printed on screen once i switched to tty1, so these are just a few example lines of many more)

So i thought my ssd (which is not new) might be broken, i booted from a usb device (ubuntu), checked SMART data but everything looked really good. So i ran memtest (1 pass) - everything okay.

At that moment i did not know what causes the problem. So i figured it has to be a corrupted installer and downloaded a new copy of ubuntu, created a new installation medium (same USB3.0 stick) and re-installed. After configuring for a while i unplugged the notebook again and the same shit happened.

So at this point it looks like the notebook is only working when plugged in.

The strange thing is - it does not simply poweroff or blackout, only the SATA bus seems to be affected by the battery mode.

Do you have any suggestions? Could exchanging the battery help? Or is it more likely some capacitor or the controller itself, that may be damaged?

The system seems to be designed to work with an hdd, so maybe there is some electrical issue (please forgive me my incompetence, i am not an engineer).

I also checked the bios, sata is configured for AHCI, not IDE mode.

I am happy for any kind of help :-)

**UPDATE**

I just noticed, that - when uplugged - the cpu load increases and is caused by upowerd, this is linux-related - i know but i thought i better add this notice.